# Hiding an added admin page menu using css

Tags: admin-menu, options

I have added an admin page in wordpress but i needed it to be hidden.I added the page successfully like this

```
function add_admin_page()
{
$themename = 'Cesaro';
$page_function = 'admin_page';
add_menu_page($themename." Options", $themename, 'edit_themes', $page_function, 'admin_page');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_admin_page');
```

To hide it,i looked at its css using firebug and discovered a pattern or so it seems.Pages added in the format i demonstrated have a css id that starts with #toplevel_page_{page_added} so the css id to the page i added is #toplevel_page_admin_page.

I went ahead and did

```
#toplevel_page_admin_page{
display:none !important;
}
```

Is this format #toplevel_page_{page added} consistent with all wordpress installations?.

Comment: Why do you want to hide it? There are ways to enable such pages for some selected users only, wouldn’t that be better?

Comment: Oh yeah,that's clever so i plan to do this if ( !is_user_logged_in() || !current_user_can('edit_posts') ) 
 wp_die(__("You are not allowed to be here"));.

Comment: I made some correction to the question.The title should have been how to hide the added admin page menu and not the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress already takes care of that for you. The third argument in your `add_menu_page` function, which reads `edit_themes` is the capability required to access the page. If the user doesn't have that capability he can't access the page, so WordPress won't show him that option on the menu. Clever, no?

Now, from the code you mention on your comments, you're restricting the page to user who can `edit_posts`. If that's what you want, just use that on the `add_menu_page` function instead. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense.

PS: If you're planning to add a theme options page, I'd suggest using the [add_theme_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page) function instead, which will nest it within the Appearance section of the menu.